# Javascript adding Vectors 2D Graphics

Tags: javascript, vector

I am fairly new to JavaScript and at the moment I am really struggling!
I am doing a 2D Graphics module, and have been given some tests that need passing on Vectors.
I am stuck on the add function.
To pass the test it says I need to:

***Add function*** – your Vector object should have an ‘add’ function that takes a single Vector object as
its parameter. The function should return a newly constructed Vector object that is the result of
adding the ‘this’ Vector with the parameter Vector.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 var Vector = (function () {
function Vector(pX, pY) {
    this.setX(pX);
    this.setY(pY);

}
Vector.prototype.getX = function () {
    return this.mX;
};
Vector.prototype.setX = function (pX) {
    this.mX = pX;
};
Vector.prototype.getY = function () {
    return this.mY;
};
Vector.prototype.setY = function (pY) {
    this.mY = pY;
}

 //this is my attempt at the add function
Vector.prototype.add = function (x, y) {
    var a = this.mX + x;
    var b = this.mY + y;
    return Vector(a, b);
}


return Vector;
 }());
```

This is the test it needs to pass:

```
  describe("Add", function () {
    var secondVector, thirdVector;
    secondVector = new Vector(20, 30, 0);
    thirdVector = vector.add(secondVector);

    it("X Set", function () {
        expect(thirdVector.getX()).toEqual(50);
    });
    it("Y Set", function () {
        expect(thirdVector.getY()).toEqual(70);
    });
});
```

Sorry if this is confusing, I am still getting the hang of terminology and understanding what everything means. Let me know if you do not understand anything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"The function should return a newly constructed Vector"* Do you see why your code my not be making a "**new**ly constructed" Vector? One little keyword makes all of the difference.

Comment: I changed it to this but it didnt help return new Vector(a, b);

Comment: [It works fine for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/99o0g838/) Make sure you [open your console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log).

Comment: This is the test it needs to pass:

Comment: describe("Add", function () {
        var secondVector, thirdVector;
        secondVector = new Vector(20, 30, 0);
        thirdVector = vector.add(secondVector);

        it("X Set", function () {
            expect(thirdVector.getX()).toEqual(50);
        });
        it("Y Set", function () {
            expect(thirdVector.getY()).toEqual(70);
        });
    });

Comment: Your `add` function takes two parameters: `x` and `y`. It does **not** take another vector. If you need your function to take a vector instead of `x` and `y`, you need to write it differently.

Comment: how would i do this? sorry i am so clueless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without just giving you the answer, let's break down the question to help you understand.

> *Add function* – your Vector object should have an ‘add’ function that takes a single Vector object as its parameter.

This is saying that you need to create a function called `add` and put it on your vector object. You have done this correctly. However, it then says **takes a single Vector object** as its parameter. You currently provide two parameters, an `x` and a `y`.

```
// this should not provide x & y, but a previously created vector
Vector.prototype.add = function (x, y) {

// so your function definition should look something like this
// where vec is a different Vector created elsewhere.
Vector.prototype.add = function(vec) {
```

> The function should return a newly constructed Vector

You almost have this correct, you are just missing the word `new`. I suggest you read more about `new` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), as it is important.

> Vector object that is the result of adding the ‘this’ Vector with the parameter Vector.

Because you are creating your `add` function on the `prototype`, whenever you use `this` inside the function, it means you are looking at the instance of the object that the `add` function was called on. What you have written there is correct. The only issue is that you are adding `x` & `y` parameters, and not the x and y from another Vector object.

Comment: Thank you!
Does this look better:

Comment: Vector.prototype.add = function (pX, pY) {
        var a = this.mX + pX;
        var b = this.mY + pY;
        return new Vector (pX, pY)
    }

Comment: ah okay so like this:

Comment: Vector.prototype.add = function (vec) {
        var a = this.mX + pX;
        var b = this.mY + pY;
        return new Vector(pX, pY);
    }

Comment: Think about `pX` now. Where does that come from, as it isn't passed to the function. Hint: Notice each vector has functions for getting x and y, `vec.getX()`.

Comment: I tried this but its still not working :  Vector.prototype.add = function (v) {
        return new Vector(this.getX + v.getX, this.getY + v.getY);
    }

Comment: Remember that `getX` is a *function*, so you need call it by doing, `getX()`.